# JQuery - get the id values from an unknown number of children from a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get a list of ID values for each group of parent divs. Using draglua a site is dragged into a group, then I would like to create a dictionary string that I can submit to a server side form and process it.

That dictionary string should contain a list of all the ids within each group, my script below currently works for one group (A) but not all groups, im assuming there is a better approach to get all groups in one?

So after a user has dragged sites into groups I would like to be able to click apply groups then the the value of site_groups is set to

```
[{group: a, ids: [3,4,5]},{group: b, ids: [31,4]},{group: c, ids: [8]},..etc]
```

I can then submit this and process it server side, is anyone able to assist?

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.min.css"
        integrity="sha256-iVhQxXOykHeL03K08zkxBGxDCLCuzRGGiTYf2FL6mLY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
        .drag-space {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
        <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
            <!-- partial -->
            <div class="main-panel">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- /.card -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                        <div><i class="fa fa-layer-group fa-fw"></i> Change Groups</div>
                                        <div class="text-muted mb-1 small">
                                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="apply-tab" href="javascript:post();">Apply group changes</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                     
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form id="sitegroups_form" method="post">
                                        <input type="text" id="site_groups" />
                                    </form>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>A - <small class="text-muted">1 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-A" class="drag-space">

                                                <div id="7">
                                                    <a href="/sites/site/7/">Aberdeen</a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>B - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-B" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>C - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-C" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>D - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-D" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>E - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-E" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>F - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-F" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>G - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-G" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>H - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-H" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <h4>I - <small class="text-muted">0 Sites</small></h4>
                                            <div id="drag-I" class="drag-space">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-body -->
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i class="fa fa-layer-group fa-fw"></i> Sites not in change Groups
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row" id="drag-source">
                                        <div id="8" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/8/">London</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="9" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/9/">New York</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="10" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/10/">Manchester</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="11" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/11/">Liverpool</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="12" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/12/">Edinburgh</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="13" class="col-3">
                                            <a href="/sites/site/13/">Tokyo</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- main-panel ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- container-scroller -->
    <!-- plugins:js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.js"
        integrity="sha256-rVf3H94DblhP4Z6wLSa2mpMwRS5qePBWykE6QWPOaO0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Begin Dragula JS
        var drake = dragula([document.querySelector('#drag-source'), document.querySelector('#drag-A'), document.querySelector('#drag-B'), document.querySelector('#drag-C'), document.querySelector('#drag-D'), document.querySelector('#drag-E'), document.querySelector('#drag-F'), document.querySelector('#drag-G'), document.querySelector('#drag-H'), document.querySelector('#drag-I'),]);

        // when item dropped
        drake.on('drag', function (el,target,source,sibling) {
            el.classList.remove('col-3');
        })
        // get the items within a group

        $("#apply-tab").click(function(){
            var a_children = document.querySelectorAll("#drag-A div");
            var a_ids = []
            for (var i = 0; i<a_children.length; i++) {
                a_ids.push(a_children[i].id)
            }
            var group_a_ids = '{group: a, ids: ['+ a_ids +']}';
            $("#site_groups").val(group_a_ids);
        });

    </script>
    <!-- End custom js for this page-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anwser your question regarding the need to account for all groups at once (without taking care of the drag and drop part), you can take benefit of the HTML class `drag-space`, as follows:

```
        $("#apply-tab").click(function(){
        var group_ids = {};

        $(".drag-space").each(function() { // Loop over all items of class 'drag-space'
          var id = this.id;
          var key = id.replace(/drag-/, "").toLowerCase();
          var children = document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + " div");
          var ids = []
          for (var i = 0; i<children.length; i++) {
            ids.push(children[i].id)
          }
          group_ids[key] = ids;
        });
        $("#site_groups").val(JSON.stringify(group_ids));
    });
```